# My Loop work just 2 times(Javascript Dice Game)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to make simple dice game when i press the images,every one of them changed just one time, that does it mean i can change the number 2 times in total. what is the problem?

```js
let dicelenght = document.querySelectorAll('img').length;

for(let i=0; i<dicelenght;i++)
 {
     let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
     let randomDice = "images/dice" + randomNum + ".png";
     let Dice = document.querySelectorAll('img');
     Dice[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
         Dice[i].setAttribute('src', randomDice);
     });
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your snippet and add relevant HTML and CSS. Also I STRONGLY recommend a delegation on the container instead of eventListener on each image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not generating the random number when the click happens. You have done that just once for every die. Instead you should only generate the random number when the user has clicked.

Also, don't query for the elements *in each iteration*: just do this once at the top:

```
let dice = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for (let die of dice) {
     die.addEventListener("click", function(){
         let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
         let randomDieSrc = "images/dice" + randomNum + ".png";
         die.setAttribute('src', randomDieSrc);
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the number on click, but please also delegate

```js
document.getElementById("diceDiv").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const img = e.target.closest("img")
  if (img) {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    img.setAttribute('src', `images/dice${randomNum}.png`);
    img.setAttribute('alt', randomNum);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="diceDiv">
  <img id="d1" alt="d1"/><img id="d2" alt="d2"/><img id="d3" alt="d3"/><br>
  <img id="d4" alt="d4"/><img id="d5" alt="d5"/><img id="d6" alt="d6"/>
</div>
```

If you only want them to click once, you can test

```js
const diceDiv = document.getElementById("diceDiv")
diceDiv.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const img = e.target.closest("img")
  if (img) {
    if (!img.alt.includes("d")) return; // already clicked
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    img.setAttribute('src', `images/dice${randomNum}.png`);
    img.setAttribute('alt', randomNum);
  }
});

document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  diceDiv.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => img.alt = img.id);
})
```

```html
<div id="diceDiv">
  <img id="d1" alt="d1" /><img id="d2" alt="d2" /><img id="d3" alt="d3" /><br>
  <img id="d4" alt="d4" /><img id="d5" alt="d5" /><img id="d6" alt="d6" />
</div>
<input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" />
```